# executeUpdate returning number of rows rather than affected rows

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, execute

```
PreparedStatement updatestmt1 = con.prepareStatement("update BASE_TX set tx_vl=replace(tx_vl,?,?)");
                    updatestmt1.setString( 1, "${parm:"+ stringToreplace.trim() +"}" );
                    updatestmt1.setString( 2, "${parm:" + replacedString.trim() + "}" );

                    int ifUpdated1 = updatestmt1.executeUpdate();
```

The ifUpdated1 is returning 14480 rather than number of affected rows which are none in the case that im running. So I'm not able to make a call if they r actually updated or not.

Comment: Yes, that's what it's supposed to do. You'll need to add a `where` clause if you want it to count something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the correct behavior. Since you don't set the `WHERE`, all rows are affected. The fact that your replace is an identity is not relevant to DB. If you really want to get affected rows, use `where` like that:

`"update BASE_TX set tx_vl=replace(tx_vl,?,?) where tx_vl != replace(tx_vl,?,?)"`

Note that it will slow your query, but reduce IO, which actually may be better in your case.

Comment: How will it reduce IO?